# Polar-cartesian coordinates integrals but different results

Tags: definite-integrals, polar-coordinates

I am trying to calculate the following integral

[$$V = \pi \int_{-16}^{-7} \left( \sqrt{256 - y^2} \right)^2 \, \mathrm{d}y $$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/egvzF.png)

I get the following result: $1053 \pi$.

But when I use the usual transformation ($x=r\cos(\theta)$, $y=r\sin(\theta)$), I get the following integral

[$$\pi \int_{-90}^{-25.94} \left(16^3\cos(\theta) - 16^3\sin^2(\theta)\cos(\theta) \right) \, \mathrm{d}\theta $$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLEMz.png)

And it results $760.43$. I should get the same results with both integrals, what am I doing wrong? I have done the transformation like 10 times :(

Comment: I don't see how this transformation helps. You can just evaluate the integral using the power rule. That's all you need. Remember, only do substitutions if it helps.

Comment: Also, polar coordinates are used when you have the integrand as a function of x and y, i.e. $f(x,y)$. This integrand is only a function of y.

Comment: In the exercise i am asked to use polar coordinates :(

Comment: Your mistake is with your bounds. You are going from -90 to -25.94, when you should be using radians. So use $-\frac{\pi}{2} \leq \theta \leq -\arcsin(\frac{7}{16})$ instead.

Comment: Also, it is not polar coordinates. They mean use a trig substitution, that's different.

Comment: i had the wrong bounds, thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 2):

To integrate, we split up the terms and use a $u$-substitution ($u = sin(\theta)$) in the second term:

$I(\theta)={\displaystyle\int}{\pi}\left(16^3\cos\left({\theta}\right)-16^3\cos\left({\theta}\right)\sin^2\left({\theta}\right)\right)\,\mathrm{d}{\theta}$=${\displaystyle\int}{\pi}\left(4096\cos\left({\theta}\right)-4096\cos\left({\theta}\right)\sin^2\left({\theta}\right)\right)\,\mathrm{d}{\theta}= {\displaystyle\int}4096{\pi}\cos\left({\theta}\right)\,\mathrm{d}{\theta} -{\displaystyle\int}4096\pi\cos\left({\theta}\right)\sin^2\left({\theta}\right)\,\mathrm{d}{\theta} =4096{\pi}\sin\left({\theta}\right)-\dfrac{4096{\pi}\sin^3\left({\theta}\right)}{3} +C$

Now plug in your bounds for $-\frac{\pi}{2}\leq \theta \leq -\arcsin(\frac{7}{16})$ to get the answer:

$I(-\arcsin(\frac{7}{16}))-I(-\frac{\pi}{2}) = 4096\pi\{-\frac{7}{16}+1\}-\frac{4096\pi}{3}\{-\frac{7^3}{16^3}+1\}=4096\pi(\frac{9}{16})-4096\frac{\pi}{3}(\frac{3753}{4096})=16^2\cdot9\pi-1251\pi=1053\pi$

Comment: thank you so much! i had the wrong bounds indeed

Comment: No problem, that's why we're here for...